# cannot execute php files inside webroot/js/ in cakephp

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

started to create a plugin for a FCKEditor with wiris . i created  folders in my plugin/webroot/js  with the editor . the problem is that the filemanager does not execute the php file inside this directory
How can i make php file to execute

wiris is a math operator plugin, i was able to integrate wiris inside fck editor. Now when i click on the wiris icon embedded in fck editor, a new window pop-up, it points to editor.php inside webroot/js/fckeditor/editor/plugins/fckeditor_wiris/integration/editor.php

now cake does not allow editor.php to execute.

i was able to get it properly working locally. But not in server.

PLease help

Comment: What does "does not execute" mean? What's the error message? Or do you just see the PHP code in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your file permissions;

```
chmod 755 -R fckeditor/
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know this is not possible for plugin asset folders:
http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/1499-support-php-script-in-plugin-assets-folder

Answer (score 0):

Just as a side note:

Running php files from webroot is not "cake" way I think. Better approach would be to put php connector code into controller and cȟange appropriate path in FCKeditor config.
That way you will also benefit from all CakePHP goodies like access control, native permission check based on authentication etc.
Maybe this article will help a bit:
http://blog.beamstyle.com.hk/tutorial-on-integrating-ckfinderckeditor-into-cakephp-with-session-authentication/